# Why onClickListener not working in Fragment?

Tags: android

I have a `fragment` in `my activity`. I'm trying to make `RelativeLayout` clicable in `fragment` but when I click it's not working, nothing happens.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:padding="5.0dip"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15.0dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="15.0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15.0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header2">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameCoin"
        android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative500coin"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons_bg"
    android:padding="5.0sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70.0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coin500Image"
        android:layout_width="38.0dip"
        android:layout_height="38.0dip"
        android:layout_marginStart="16.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/coin_count_image"
        android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="38.0dip"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/coin500Image"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TextView
            android:textSize="20.0sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="15.0dip"
            android:paddingRight="15.0dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.0dip"
            android:text="@string/coin_500"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="15.0dip"
            android:paddingRight="15.0dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/coin_500_text"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/coin_500_price"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:tint="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment.java:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    RelativeLayout relative500coin = view.findViewById(R.id.relative500coin);
    relative500coin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            bp.consumePurchase("coin_500");
            bp.purchase(getActivity(), "coin_500");
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

This all my code what I'm doing in xml and java. But I could not find any error. Any body have a idea what is wrong here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure nothing happens? You should add a log or Toast inside the `onClick()` method.

Comment: I added Log.d("Click", "True"); also nothing happened..

Comment: What if you remove `android:focusable="true` from that view?

Comment: I removed still same..

Comment: remove your onClick function from onCreateview, try to implement onClickListener interface on your Fragment. and Override the onClick function.

Comment: Can you make a example please @KP

Answer (score 0):

```
private void navigateToViewDetailProgress(View view) {
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             (Do your onclick action here)
            }
         }
    }
```

Call above function in onResume of your Fragment. make sure you pass rootview as a function parameter.